# Find an upper bound for an objective function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonconvex-programming, bounds, approximation

My objective function is $\log_2(1+{x^2y^2})$ and I found two upper bounds for $x^2$ and $y^2$.

For example, assumed that we have the following upper bounds:
$x^2\leq\text{constant}_1^2$ and $y^2\leq\text{constant}_2^2$.

So, my question is: could we say that $\log_2(1+{x^2y^2})\leq \log_2(1+{\text{constant}_1^2\cdot\text{constant}_2^2})$? If so, how tight is this bound?

Comment: I would start with using $x^2y^2$ as objective.

Comment: Actually, the main objective function is $\sum_{i}\log_2(1+x_i^2y_i^2)$

Answer (score 5):

Yes, because $\log$ is monotonic, it preserves inequalities. The tightness depends on your other constraints.